# If Statement Not Acting As Expected

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    logger();
});
function logger()
    {
        if(localStorage.getItem("status") === null)
            {
                $("#test").html("Not logged in.");
                $("#buttonlogin").click(function(){
                    var ul = $("#userlogin").val();
                    var pl = $("#passlogin").val();
                    $.post("includes/logger.php", {type : "login", user : ul, pass : pl}, function(dlogin){
                        if(dlogin == 1)
                            {
                                $("#outlogin").html("Please enter a username.");
                                $("#userlogin").focus();
                            }
                        else if(dlogin == 2)
                            {
                                $("#outlogin").html("Please enter password.");
                                $("#passlogin").focus();
                            }
                        else if(dlogin == 3)
                            {
                                $("#outlogin").html("This username doesn't exist.");
                                $("#userlogin").focus();
                            }
                        else if(dlogin == 4)
                            {
                                $("#outlogin").html("This username and password don't match.");
                                $("#userlogin").focus();
                            }
                        else
                            {
                                localStorage.setItem("status", dlogin);
                                logger();
                            }
                    });
                });
                $("#buttonregister").click(function(){
                    var ur = $("#userregister").val();
                    var pr = $("#passregister").val();
                    var cpr = $("#confirmpassregister").val();
                    $.post("includes/logger.php", {type : "register", user : ur, pass : pr, cpass : cpr}, function(dregister){
                        if(dregister == 1)
                            {
                                $("#outregister").html("Please enter a username.");
                                $("#userregister").focus();
                            }
                        else if(dregister == 2)
                            {
                                $("#outregister").html("Please enter a password.");
                                $("#passregister").focus();
                            }
                        else if(deregister == 3)
                            {
                                $("#outregister").html("Please enter a confirm password.");
                                $("#cpassregister").focus();
                            }
                        else if(dregister == 4)
                            {
                                $("#outregister").html("Password and confirm password do not match.");
                                $("#passregister").focus();
                            }
                        else if(dregister == 5)
                            {
                                $("#outregister").html("This username is already taken.");
                                $("#userregister").focus();
                            }
                        else
                            {
                                localStorage.setItem("status", dregister);
                                logger();
                            }
                    });
                });
            }
        else
            {
                $("#test").html("You are logged in.");
                $("#buttonlogout").click(function(){
                    localStorage.removeItem("status");
                    logger();
                });
            }
    }
```

The above code is meant to check whether or not a localStorage variable is in existence or not. If it is then only allow the log out button to be pressed. If is doesn't then let the two forms to work. Once it is done with either it is supposed to recheck if the variable is set and then do as I said above. However it ignores it when a user logs in and allows the forms to run. If you refresh however it works fine. I cannot for the life of me figure out why this is happening, and it is beginning to piss me off. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Try like so: `if(!localStorage.getItem("status"))`

Comment: Still works the same way. Interesting way to check if it exists or not though.

Comment: Did you validate if dlogin response is correct ? because the only place where you set localstorage variable is in the else statement .

Comment: Yes I did Sandcar. The problem was that .click binds elements, which is was unaware of. Thank you though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On your `else` statement, try adding:

```
$('#buttonlogin').unbind('click');
$('#buttonregister').unbind('click');
```

If I understand your problem correctly, what's happening is those events are registered when you first run `$("#buttonlogin").click(function()...`.

It doesn't matter that you call `logger()` again and the `if` statement is false the second time around. If you want to disable these callbacks you have to do it explicitly.

Comment: Will do but a quick question does that mean jQuery .click is essentially .bind('click')? If so that would make so much sense.

Comment: It's essentialy .on('click', handler). 'bind' is sort of deprecated since 1.7

Comment: Well either way .bind and .on are essentially the same. So it is doing a bind though that makes so much sense. Thanks so much.